# Chartjs bar-chart does not render when values are equal

Tags: chart.js

i'm stuck on a stupid issue with chartjs, i just tried to create something like "hello world" bar chart, but chartjs 2.7.2 version does not render values if they are equal:

```
   var popCanvas1 =  document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");
   var barChart = new Chart(popCanvas1, {
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
           labels: [ "0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "91-100" ],
           datasets: [{
               label: 'test',
               data: [16, 21, 15, 28, 39, 38, 34, 34, 22, 15],
               backgroundColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)'
               ]
           }]
       },
       options: {
           title: {
               display: true,
               text: 'Title Text'
           }
       }
   });
```

in the rendered image i have no any bar for data values that equal to 15, can anyone help with such thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15 is the smallest number in your dataset. Depending on how Chart.js determines the linear y-axis scale, it might start at 15. This means no bar is drawn as the value is equal to the lowest point of the y-axis, i.e.:

[image]

You can fix the issue by adding the `beginAtZero` property to your chart `options`:

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Title Text'
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tim! It's exactly what i need!